# Salesforce Flows

Tags: flowscreen, flow-screen-component

I got a Question regrading the Screen Flow !!
I added the Flow in the User Interface of Account object to Create Contact !!
It was working fine !!

Now I deactivated the flow form the setup but haven't removed it from the User Interface

And when I use this Flow on the User Interface it is Still working!!
Is this a Kind of Glitch flow has??

Comment: Can you try with user who does not have Manage Flow  permission? Is it still working?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with our Product team on this. This behaviour is expected Only with users having "Manage Flow " permission.

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url.htm&type=5)

> Only users with the Manage Flow permission can run inactive flows. If the flow contains subflow elements, the referenced flows must also have an active version.